# Configure Safenet Luna EFT HSM to allow ISO-0 to ISO-1 pin translation

Tags: hsm, gemalto, hardware-security-module, safenet

As the title states I need to be able to convert an ISO-0 formatted encrypted pin block to ISO-1 format using a Safenet(Gemalto) Luna EFT.  I am connecting over TCP/IP and sending commands formatted per programmer's guide.

I am using PIN-TRANSLATE-2 EE0602 and getting back a 06 error code indicating to me that it won't allow the conversion from ISO 0 to 1.

I know this can somehow be enabled via HSM configuration.  Can someone please show me how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer the product documentation:

Luna EFT Administration Console > Payment Configuration > PIN Security > PIN Conversion

Comment: Thanks Jia.  Checked the document.  I assume it is totally impossible to enable this if your HSM is setup in pci mode?

Comment: In our case we have a web UI for configuration and it looks like you can select the reformatting from ISO-0 to ISO-1, but when you send the command over TCP/IP it gives you a 06 error code which means only ISO-0 or ISO-3 supported.